# How to convert from a unicode code point to an actual unicode string in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a file with a list of unicode code points:

```
0x9C00
0x9D70
0x9D6B
0xFA2D
```

I'm trying to create an array of unicode characters, like so:

```
with open("KANJI.TXT") as f:
    kanjiCodes = f.readlines()

alphabet = [
    code_point for code_point in kanjiCodes
]
```

How can I convert these 0x strings to actual unicode strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.x you could do as follows:

```
kanjiCodes=['0x9C00', '0x9D70','0x9D6B', '0xFA2D']

print([chr(int(code_point, 16)) for code_point in kanjiCodes])
# ['鰀', '鵰', '鵫', '鶴']
```

Answer (score 1):

use unichr

```
print unichr(0x9C00)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the main problem, which is that the character code is already represented as a string. (Also, I should have mentioned I'm using python 3, so it would just be chr(0x9C00))